# Anchor tag href link is not working in ms edge browser while same is working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, microsoft-edge

Anchor tag href is not working in ms edge browser, here is my code image[function imagre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdMnO.jpg) the same code running in internet explorer here is the actual result that i want
[Result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8idSB.jpg)

I am expecting to run my code in ms edge for href link,
When client click on link the result needs to be display as per attached image

Comment: Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue** so that we can test in Edge. The code you provide is not enough to reproduce the issue. Besides, please don't provide image.